# How can I effectively create a prompt for generating High-Quality, Realistic app UI Designs with Dalle3?

Tags: chatgpt, image-generation, dall-e

As an app developer, I've successfully utilized [Midjourney](https://www.midjourney.com/explore) for crafting mobile app designs, but I'm seeking to leverage Dalle3, particularly its integration with ChatGPT, for similar purposes.

My goal is to generate app UI designs that are not only creative but also realistic and practical for development.

For example, let's say I entered this prompt into **Midjourney**:

> Create a modern music streaming app design with the colors orange white and green

This would result in a *good* image:

[image]

However, if I enter the *same* prompt into ChatGPT (with Dalle), it would result in a *terrible* app design, as you can see:

[image]

---

- What are some good prompt tips to generate *realistic* app design images using Dalle?

**Note:**

I did try to give a few more details to ChatGPT to get better results, however, whatever I tried, the images didn't look realistic.